# Which platforms should I compile to via 'go build'?

Tags: go, build, operating-system, cross-compiling, cpu-architecture

I have this list of supported platforms by the go builder:

```
    "darwin/386",
    "darwin/amd64",
    "dragonfly/amd64",
    "freebsd/386",
    "freebsd/amd64",
    "freebsd/arm",
    "linux/386",
    "linux/amd64",
    "linux/arm",
    "linux/arm64",
    "linux/ppc64",
    "linux/ppc64le",
    "linux/mips",
    "linux/mipsle",
    "linux/mips64",
    "linux/mips64le",
    "linux/s390x",
    "nacl/386",
    "nacl/amd64p32",
    "nacl/arm",
    "netbsd/386",
    "netbsd/amd64",
    "netbsd/arm",
    "openbsd/386",
    "openbsd/amd64",
    "openbsd/arm",
    "plan9/386",
    "plan9/amd64",
    "plan9/arm",
    "solaris/amd64",
    "windows/386",
    "windows/amd64",
```

I am working on a script to cross-compile my project. I started by including them all, but now I added some more code to my project and I couldn't compile it for Plan9. I looked Plan9 up and saw that it's really old and not used anymore. So my question is, which platforms are actually used and worth compiling to?

Comment: Only you can answer "what is worth it" for you.

Comment: Whichever ones *you* need to compile for. The community cannot answer this for you.

Comment: @Adrian: Well that's the thing. I could build it for every platform, but I was asking what the community is actually using? Are there any people who host a server on Plan9? Do I have to include that? What is the majority of linux distros that I sould support? But I get what you mean, there might not be "the answer" for this question.

Comment: "The community" does not have homogenous needs. Build for the platforms that your target user base demands, not what StackOverflow happens to be building arbitrary projects for. There is no reasonable community answer to this question.

Comment: "Are there any people who host a server on Plan9?" -- Obvoiusly there are people who use Plan 9, otherwise nobody would have ported Go to it. "Do I have to include that?" -- You don't have to do anything. "What is the majority of linux distros that I sould support?" -- Linux distros don't really fit into this question at all. Compile for one distro, and it'll work for all others.

Answer (score 1):

To list all supported platforms (`GOOS/GOARCH` combinations), use the following command:

```
go tool dist list
```

Take this list as a superset of platforms you want to / have to build to, and filter out those you don't need (e.g. android). Don't try to build to platforms not included in this list, it will fail.

For me (Go 1.13.3 linux/amd64) it outputs:

```
aix/ppc64
android/386
android/amd64
android/arm
android/arm64
darwin/386
darwin/amd64
darwin/arm
darwin/arm64
dragonfly/amd64
freebsd/386
freebsd/amd64
freebsd/arm
illumos/amd64
js/wasm
linux/386
linux/amd64
linux/arm
linux/arm64
linux/mips
linux/mips64
linux/mips64le
linux/mipsle
linux/ppc64
linux/ppc64le
linux/s390x
nacl/386
nacl/amd64p32
nacl/arm
netbsd/386
netbsd/amd64
netbsd/arm
netbsd/arm64
openbsd/386
openbsd/amd64
openbsd/arm
openbsd/arm64
plan9/386
plan9/amd64
plan9/arm
solaris/amd64
windows/386
windows/amd64
windows/arm
```